# how to use same name class libraries on a solution

Tags: c#, .net, class-library

Need to add two same name .csproj class libraries in my solution.Have two project but unfortunately those project class libraries names are same,like: Hello.csproj.I try to add existing project on solution then show me error

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx
from above url I learned how to use same namespace dll on same project ,but I need help how to use same classlibraries on a solution

if have any query please ask,thanks in advanced.

[image]

**Note**:ok people want to know the reason,i have two project on Autocat 2005 and 2010,now want to merge those project on one solution,2010 update base on 2005 so class libraries are same,but i need to use both of them.So problem arise and seeking help.

Comment: GETah thanks for reply,why it's not possible.is there any trick to solve this issue

Comment: I don't see why this is a 'NEED'.  There is no justification for this under any scenario I can imagine.  If the class libraries do the same thing, discard one, if they don't, then give them distinct names.  Be glad MS prevents you from shooting yourself in the foot in this regard.

Comment: GrayFox37 thanks for reply,i don't say those do same thing,actually those are different project but unfortunately those class library names are same ,when i merge those project in one solution and try to add references to use those project from parent one .Face problem and seeking help

Comment: What the f is FooVersion1 and FooVersion2??  Is this a real question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really must do this, then ensure the second project has a different name, and then change the namespaces of the classes in the second project (normally the project name comprises the first part of the namespace - just change that part). The classes will still be identical internally, but because they have a different namespace they will be distinct entities. This will lead to very smelly code though when you start mixing them up in the ClientApp - to avoid confusion make sure you always refer to them by their full namespace (i.e. do not have a `using xyz.myclassname;` statement at the top of the class file that uses them).

Maybe you want to run two (almost identical) instances of the same service or something, but as mentioned it is hard to think of a genuine reason why you would *need* to do this. If you are looking to have two identical looking instances but different implementation then you will want to use interfaces instead.

**Edit:** Visual Studio will not allow you to have two identically named projects, and you are playing crazy games if you change a project name but don't change its project GUID (in the .proj file and the .sln file).

The simplest thing for you to do here is to create a new **empty** project in the solution explorer, right click on it and *Open folder in Explorer*, then copy the class files from the original project to the new one, then back in the solution explorer choose *Show all files* (little button at the top of the solution explorer), then select the newly added files under the new project, right click, *Add to project*. (These menu options are from memory, they should be roughly right).

Comment: i can not add those classlibraries ,then how can use them.it's not so clear.

Comment: slugster thanks for reply,using your technique i can add classlibraries,but how to use them.now i capable to add references of both file ,fail to use them,show me some guide line how to use them.

Comment: need help how to  Import the namespace of reference dll

Comment: The answer bellow should be the selected answer. My case is a bit less controversial, because a plugin is building with a project reference that the parent app uses, but it doesn't use the same version, so the namespaces can be the same.

Comment: @GettnDer that will all work nicely until you run into namespace issues. As I mentioned VS doesn't let you do this naturally and there's very good reasons for that. You'll also notice that I detailed something very similar to the answer below in case the user insists on going against advice and best practice.

Comment: Except you shouldn't.
If project A references project Rv1 and plugin B references project Rv2 and project A, one of two things happen.

*  A has a public dependency to Rv1 and B needs to reference Rv1 not Rv2
* A has a private dependency to Rv1 and B can reference anything he wants, so there will be no namespace issues

This does require that at least Rv1 is signed

Answer (score 3):

You can have projects with the same name as long as they are already created in different folders and they are in different solution folders. If the projects are already created, do this to add them to your solution:

1. Add your first project to the solution.
2. In Solution Explorer window, right click your solution and select **Add->New Solution Folder**
3. Give a name to the newly created folder.
4. Right click the folder and select **Add->Existing Project**
5. Navigate to your second project and double-click the .csproj file.

You're done.

Comment: Md.Unicorn thanks for your reply.now i capable to add same class libraries ,but face problems to use those references in one class library,help me to use those references on one class .

Comment: need help how to  Import the namespace of reference dll

Comment: @shamim: Sorry for late reply. If they have exactly the same namespace and assembly name, I'm afraid you cannot use them in a single project. But if they have different namespaces, it will be strait-forward.

Comment: You should really consider changing namespaces at least.